# Why SQL statement is taking so long to execute PL/SQL when using variables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-indexes

I have an table with 10 000 000 random numbers.This statement is executed in about 2 seconds (without making indexes)'select count(1) from myTableName where x + 200 < 500', but if I create an index on (x + 200) I get the result of this query in something lower than 0.1 seconds. 
So, if I am doing something like this :

```
declare
    cursor example is
        select count(1) countOf from padure where x + 200 < 500;
begin
    for i in example loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.countOf);
    end loop;
end;
```

I get the all block executed in 0.2 seconds, but, If I am doing it in this way :

```
declare
    nbr constant integer := 200;
    cursor example is
        select count(1) countOf from padure where x + nbr < 500;
begin
    for i in example loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.countOf);
    end loop;
end;
```

I get the result in about 2 seconds. 
Why it needs so much time in order to execute this query when I use a variable instead? 
How can I avoid this? Or how can achieve the same time execution as in first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
nbr constant integer := 200;
other_nbr constant integer := 500 - nbr;
```

And then

```
select count(1) countOf 
from padure 
where x < other_nbr;
```

Create one index for just `x` and should works ok.

The problem is when you use a variable index dont know the value is 200 and have to evaluate each row

This way you only have a constant number and index can works fine.

General rule, any function over the field make the index unusable.

Comment: If I will do this the query will not use my index. My question is why the 'same' query is executed faster if I don't use a variable?

Comment: I explain it. Because a constant number isnt the same as a variable. And index dont know the variable is 200 the same as your index.

Comment: Actually it is using my index. If I run this inside the code `execute immediate 'explain plan for select count(1) from padure where x + nbr < 500'` and then output the plan, it looks like it was an index range scan.

Comment: then show us the explain plan. And why you dont try my solution?

Comment: Because I know it will work, but I don't have exactly this index. It will also work if I will do something like `open cursorName for myQuery using nbr` and define a dynamic variable instead of nbr, but I want to know why it doesn't work in the way defined above. 
Here https://imgur.com/a/yDGuD is the plan for 

`execute immediate 'explain plan for select count(1) from padure where x + ' || nbr || ' < 500';`

Comment: That query doesnt match the one in your question :(

Comment: If you know how make it work what is the problem? I already explain if you modify the field wont match the index.

Comment: This is the same query. I said, I want to find why this is taking so long in the second case and why If I am using variable in execute immediate statement it looks like it is using index.

Comment: isnt the same. Your question doesnt have `|| nbr || ` Show query and execution plan for both queries.

Comment: Ok, I think you're right, If I am concatenating the variable in such a way `|| nbr ||` it is converted to string and then executed. This means that these two are equivallent `'explain plan for select count(1) from padure where x + ' || nbr || ' < 500';` and `'explain plan for select count(1) from padure where x + 200 < 500';`.

Comment: Yes, that is why you should post the whole thing so we can see and give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I was wrong about dynamic queries and If I open a cursor and bind variables to query it doesn't have the same execution time. Then, let say I have two indexes, one is x + 200 and another is x + 300, how can I achieve the same execution time when defining a cursor or something like that? The idea is that sometimes I will need to get all rows from a query like `select ... x + 200 < 500` but sometimes I will use `x + 300 < 500`;

Comment: Is there a way to loop through all rows from an execute immediate statement?